# How to express Bessel Functions in terms of Hankel Functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, expression-manipulation

I have the following expression

```
BesselJ[\[ImaginaryI]*m, k*r]
```

[`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) knows how to transform from `HankelH1` to `BesselJ`, but not the other way around (see comment by @flinty
).

**How can I force *Mathematica* expressiosn using `BesselJ` in terms of `HankelH1` and `HankelH2`?**

Comment: Mathematica doesn't want to `FunctionExpand` the Bessel functions into Hankel functions, but it works the other way round if you look at the documentation for HankelH1/H2. We have: `HankelH1[I m, k r] == BesselJ[I*m, k*r] + I BesselY[I*m, k*r]`  and `HankelH2[I m, k r] == BesselJ[I m, k r] - I BesselY[I m, k r]` and so therefore `FullSimplify[HankelH1[I m, k r] + HankelH2[I m, k r]]/2` gives `BesselJ[I m, k r]`

Comment: One could have expected that `FullSimplify` would accept options like `TargetFunctions->{HankelH1,HankelH2}`, but it doesn't.

Comment: Might check what W|A can do: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+besselj+to+Hankel

Answer (score 8):

For a simple expression that doesn't require simplification, it should be enough to use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) with a suitable substitution (see the answer by @BobHanlon for a way to deduce this rule programmatically). I define `B2H` to be the operator form of `ReplaceAll`,

```
 B2H = ReplaceAll[
    {
      BesselJ[a_, b_] :>   (HankelH1[a, b] + HankelH2[a, b])/2,
      BesselY[a_, b_] :> I*(HankelH2[a, b] - HankelH1[a, b])/2
    }
 ]

BesselJ[\[ImaginaryI]*m, k*r]  //B2H
(*(HankelH1[\[ImaginaryI] m,k r]+HankelH2[\[ImaginaryI] m,k r])/2 *)
```

But if you need to use [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) on a more complex expression, then you will need to explicitly force `BesselJ` and `BesselY` to be *expensive functions* (using [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)), and offer a way to go from *Bessel* to *Hankel* functions, like before, (by using [`TransformationFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html)), so the following should work.

We create our own `ComplexityFunction` by taking the regular `SimplifyCount` and adding a large number for expression with `BesselJ` or `BesselY`, similar to the example in the documentation for [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

```
myCF=Function[{e}, 
          100 Count[e, _BesselJ|_BesselY, {0, Infinity}]
        + Simplify`SimplifyCount[e]
     ];
```

Now we can call `FullSimplify` using `myCF` and `B2H` as customized options.

```
FullSimplify[
    BesselJ[\[ImaginaryI]*m, k*r]
    ,ComplexityFunction->myCF
    ,TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,B2H}
]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for Bessel functions in terms of Hankel functions

```
sol = Solve[(# == FunctionExpand[#]) & /@ {HankelH1[n, z], 
    HankelH2[n, z]}, {BesselJ[n, z], BesselY[n, z]}]

(* {{BesselJ[n, z] -> 1/2 (HankelH1[n, z] + HankelH2[n, z]), 
  BesselY[n, z] -> -(1/2) I (HankelH1[n, z] - HankelH2[n, z])}} *)
```

Convert solutions to generalized replacement rules

```
rulesBtoH = Rule @@@ Thread[{
    (sol[[1, All, 1]] /. {n :> n_, z :> z_}),
    sol[[1, All, 2]]}]

(* {BesselJ[n_, z_] -> 1/2 (HankelH1[n, z] + HankelH2[n, z]), 
 BesselY[n_, z_] -> -(1/2) I (HankelH1[n, z] - HankelH2[n, z])} *)
```

Use replacement rules for conversion

```
BesselJ[I*m, k*r] /. rulesBtoH

(* 1/2 (HankelH1[I m, k r] + HankelH2[I m, k r]) *)
```