# Can Mathematica simplify expressions with prescribed relations?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I have a linear map $T$ on a vector space which satisfies $T^4 = 1$ and want to simplify expressions of the form:
$$[X,TY] + [Y,TX] + [Y,T[TX,TY]] + [X,T[TX,TY]],$$
where $[\cdot, \cdot]$ denotes the Lie bracket.

Can Mathematica simplify such expressions? I'm sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: Did you try to impose the relation as a replacement rule?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What simplifications do you expect? In your formula there are no terms of $\ge 4$ order in $T$.

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but you have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please [edit] your question to improve it. One option, similar to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259123/10397), would be to use the `TransformationFunctions` options on `FullSimplify`.